# Spacing above/below hlines in tabularray

Tags: tabularray

I have started to use the `tabularray` for my tables, I find the interface very effective and clean, but there is still something I am not able to do. For example, I want to reduce the space between lines, which I can easily do with `rowsep`, but at the same time I would like to keep some space around `hlines`. Surprisingly, there is no command to independently set the space above/below `hlines`. The only solution I found is to specify `belowsep` and `abovesep` for the adjacent lines, as shown in the example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{width=13cm,
    colspec={Q[l,3.5]rrrr},
    rowsep=0pt,
    row{1,8}={belowsep=2pt},
    row{2}={abovesep=2pt}}
        & Produzione &Ingrosso & Dettaglio & Totale\\
  \hline
  Acquisti              & ---        & 125     & 250  &\\
  Imposta a credito     & ---        &  25     &   0  &\\
  Remunerazione fattori (V.A.)   & 100     & 100  & 100 & 300 \\
  Vendite (prezzo netto)& 100        & 200     & 350  &\\
  Imposta a debito      & 25         &  50     &   0  &\\
  Vendite (prezzo lordo)& 125        & 250     & 350  & \\
  Imposta versata       & 25         &  25     &   0  & 50  \\
  \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

which gives what I want:
[image]

However, I wonder if there is a better way. If this is the only, way, I wonder if there is a command to specify the last line (in this case number 8), so that I don't have to put the number by hand and change in all tables and change it when I change the number of the rows.

Comment: Don't X, Y, and Z specify the last 3 rows or columns? Also A, B, and C specify the first 3 rows or columns.

Comment: with the Library booktabs in documentation section 5.2 \specialrule{0.8pt,blue3}{2pt}{2pt}

Comment: Thank you, `\specialrule` works, but it seems that for some reason it is not possible to define a new rule (e.g. `\newcommand{\myrule}{\specialrule{.4pt}{2pt}{2pt}}` and then use it in the `tblr`. This means that I must explicitly insert a `\specialrule` command every time I want to use it.

Comment: I solved this: I realized I am supposed to use `\NewTableCommand` instead of `\newcommand`